# Django admin select dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a field in my model called day. I want in the admin area to have a pre populate dropdown for this field instead of the text input. I have search and cant find a solution.

```
<select name="day" id="day">
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
class Timetable(models.Model):

    gym_class = models.ForeignKey('GymClass', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    time_slot = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey('Trainer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gym_class.name
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import GymClass, Category, Trainer, Timetable

admin.site.register(GymClass)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Trainer)
admin.site.register(Timetable)
```

Comment: Haven't tested this but I think another way aside from the current answer is to add [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) to the `day` field in your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to modify `ModelForm` that is used in your admin. We change widget that is used by `day`, so instead of text `<input>` it will show `<select>`.

```
class TimetableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Timetable
        widgets = {
            'day': forms.Select(choices=[('Monday', 'Monday'), ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'), ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'), ('Thursday', 'Thursday')]),
        }


class TimetableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TimetableForm


admin.site.register(Timetable, TimetableAdmin)
```